# start a function when click on circle - leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I make some circles in `JS` as follow:

```
L.circle(
  [46.765735535841024, 23.58344078063965], 5, {
    color: "blue"
  }).addTo(map).bindPopup("Description: This is my description");
```

I want to replace that `bindPopup` with a function. When I click the circle, instead of my description display, I want to run a function, for example I made this function:

```
function circleClick() {
     // my implementations;
}
```

Would someone tell me how could I do this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply assign your `circleClick` function as listener on each of your circles:

```js
L.circle(
  [46.765735535841024, 23.58344078063965], 5, {
    color: "blue"
  }
).addTo(map).on("click", circleClick);
// more L.circle's...

function circleClick(e) {
    var clickedCircle = e.target;

  // do something, like:
  clickedCircle.bindPopup("some content").openPopup();
}
```

Alternatively, you can gather all your circles within a [Feature Group](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#featuregroup), and attach the event listener to that group only:

```js
var group = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);

L.circle(
  [46.765735535841024, 23.58344078063965], 5, {
    color: "blue"
  }
).addTo(group);
// more L.circle's...

group.on("click", function (e) {
    var clickedCircle = e.layer; // e.target is the group itself.

  // do something, like:
  clickedCircle.bindPopup("some content").openPopup();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your nice feedback!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to assign the circle to a variable and then listen to click event.

```
var circle = L.circle(...).addTo(map);

circle.on('click', function (e) {
    alert("Hello, circle!");
});
```

Comment: This way works when I have only one circle. But when I have more circles, what could I do the same thing?

Comment: @Alex if you mean you need to access some data specific to the clicked circle, you can refer to the latter through [`e.target`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#events-target) where `e` is the event listener argument.

Comment: No, I have many circles like this: `L.circle( [lat, lng], 5, {color: "blue"}).addTo(map).bindPopup("Description: This is my description");` and I want to run that function when I click any of these circles.

Comment: This is my code: http://i.imgur.com/Ctksb7O.png and the function will work only for the first circle, but I want the same thing for all of them.

Comment: @Alex you should have an "edit" link below your question. Please edit your question to add your code, rather than linking an image in comments… Thank you!