# How can I create an ionic popover from a leafletjs polygon?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, ionic3

I am using Leaflet JS to draw polygons on a map.

I am able to draw the shapes, and to save the shapes to a database as GeoJSON like this:

**.ts file**

```
...
    let layer = event.layer;
    let geometry = layer.toGeoJSON();
    this.drawLayer.addLayer(layer);
}
```

I call a method in the `ngOnInit` method to redraw the shapes:

```
drawPolygonShape(data) {
    if (data.polygon.geometry) {
        let shape = {
            type: data.polygon.type,
            geometry: {
                type: data.polygon.geometry.type,
                coordinates: data.polygon.geometry.coordinates
            },
            properties: {}
        };

        L.geoJSON(shape, {
            onEachFeature: this.onEachFeature
        }).addTo(this.myMap);
    }
}


...


onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on('click', event => {
        // layer.bindPopup('Hello World'); // Works great
        let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create('MyComponent', { layer: layer });
        popover.present();
    });
}
```

I am importing `MyComponent` into the module file, so I know it is available. However, I am always getting the following error message:

> Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

So, somewhere there is a timing or scope problem that is not correctly working with the click event.

It seems like a scope problem, as any component gives the same error. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

Thank you to @ghybs I've tried adding `this` as a third argument to the click event, but I'm still getting the same error:

```
    onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on('click', event => {
        // layer.bindPopup('Hello World'); // Works great
        let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create('MyComponent', { layer: layer });
        popover.present();
    }, this);
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Thank you @ghybs!

I'm curious about your second suggestion - I am setting up the map like this:

```
let mapOptions: any = {
    position: 'topright',
    draw: {
        polyline: false,
        ...
    }
}

...

let drawControl = new L.Control.Draw(mapOptions);
this.myMap.addControl(drawControl);

this.myMap.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, this.onCreatePolygon.bind(this));
```

The `.bind(this)` makes more sense now - `onCreatePolygon` is a method I am using to save the shape.

How do you suggest I delegate to the click event for each shape?

```
this.myMap.on(L.Draw.Event.CLICK, this.MYCLICKHANDLER.bind(this));
```

(it's obvious I'm not familiar working with this so I appreciate all of your time.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Leaflet- marker click event works fine but methods of the class are undefined in the callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48170860/leaflet-marker-click-event-works-fine-but-methods-of-the-class-are-undefined-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you have a *double* context issue since you also pass your `onEachFeature` method that will get invoked with a `this` context that is already different from your class instance.

You could do `onEachFeature: this.onEachFeature.bind(this)` together with your `layer.on("click", cb, this)`

You could also use event delegation by attaching the listener on your GeoJSON Layer Group instead of each individual feature, so that you get rid of one of the context:

```js
var geoJsonData = {
  "type": "Point",
  "coordinates": [2.35, 48.86]
};

class Component {
  constructor(mapId) {
    this.myMap = L.map(mapId).setView([48.86, 2.35], 11);

    L.geoJSON(geoJsonData).addTo(this.myMap).on("click", event => {
      console.log(event.target); // this is the GeoJSON Layer Group.
      console.log(event.layer); // this is the individual child feature.
      let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create('MyComponent');
      popover.present();
    }, this); // Not even needing the 3rd arg since you use a fat arrow function, which does not have its own context.

    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(this.myMap);
  }
}

Component.prototype.popoverCtrl = { // Dummy popoverCtrl
  create(content) {
    dummyPopoverContent = content;
    return {
      present() {
        alert(dummyPopoverContent);
      },
    };
  },
};

var dummyPopoverContent = '';

new Component('map');
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet-src.js" integrity="sha512-IkGU/uDhB9u9F8k+2OsA6XXoowIhOuQL1NTgNZHY1nkURnqEGlDZq3GsfmdJdKFe1k1zOc6YU2K7qY+hF9AodA==" crossorigin=""></script>

<div id="map" style="height: 180px"></div>
```

See also [start a function when click on circle - leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35813367/start-a-function-when-click-on-circle-leaflet/35815915#35815915)

---

As for your last question, with the 1st remark above you could re-write:

```js
this.myMap.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, this.onCreatePolygon.bind(this));
```

into:

```js
this.myMap.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, this.onCreatePolygon, this);
```

Event delegation does not seem relevant in this case since you already attach a *single* listener on your map, not on individual layers.

Comment: You are amazing. Thank you SO much for the explanation. I am curious to learn about your second approach. I think it is similar to how I am setting up the map to draw. I have updated my question to include it at the end. Is your suggestion similar?

Comment: See the code example for event delegation with Leaflet Layer Groups. I am not sure I totally understand your last question, hopefully the edited answer will address it.

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your time. You have been a tremendous help!!